# How to you detect when a view render is complete using backbone and Mustache?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, mustache

I'm using Backbone along with Mustache, how can I detect when a view is done rendering a mustache template? I want to apply the tipsy tooltip plugin after all the items are there but if I add this to render, it is called for ever since item in the collection/model?

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your app better? It sounds like you have many views being rendered and all of them require this plugin? The title of your question doesn't make sense because views render instantly and there is no asynchronous issue to deal with here. So the problem is in your own code path somewhere, which we cannot see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put your tipsy code after the line that adds the Mustache template to the dom?

for example this is what I have in my navView:

```
$(this.el).html(Mustache.to_html(navTemplate, this.model.toJSON()));
$('body').prepend(this.el);
this.$('img').twipsy({trigger:'hover', placement:  'below', fallback:'test', offset:10});
```

It adds twipsy (the twitter bootstrap version of tipsy) after my nav has rendered and been added to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

My app sends a trigger 'model-loaded' at the end of the render method. The listeners (in your case, twipsy) can extend the view behavior.